# How to delete all array if i select one of its item in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have two collection views.

1)Main

2)Sub

at `DidSelect` Method main and sub Items is added to `UITableView`

Main Product is related to sub items.

Suppose in main collection view I have iPhone when I will click on iPhone it will added to cart and sub collection view will open

#### Code to Add product in tableview

```
  arrProductCart.insertObject(dictSub, atIndex: 0)
  arrMainProduct.addObject(dictSub)
```

Sub collection view contain products related to main items.

Suppose i choose iPhone than subitems will be charger and headphone.

My requirement is when i delete main product its related sub items should be deleted from tableview

#### How i am deleting individual product

```
    func btnDeleteTapped(sender: UIButton){
    arrProductCart.removeObjectAtIndex(sender.tag)
    tblCart.reloadData()
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Scriptable please check updated question. if it is insufficient detail plz tell me

Comment: `Array` type has a function `removeAll(keepCapacity keepCapacity: Bool = default)` that does exactly what it's supposed to - removes all the elements from the array. Any particular reason why that doesn't work? Do you have a reference to the adjoined subitems array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not doing that from a UX point of view.

Think of the situation where a user adds an iPhone and then headphones and a charger as subitems.

Now they add an iPad but no accessories (because they have them already in the cart).

Then they decide they no longer want the iPhone.

What should now happen to the iPhone subitems?

If you DO want to do this then you could store the cart almost recursively. Have a cart that includes an iPhone. But the iPhone also has an additional cart that includes the accessories.

The whole thing can be displayed as a single cart but now when you delete the iPhone the accessories will delete also.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. suppose i have many items in cart.iphone and its sub products are also in cart. than how i will differentiate that which product is main item for all sub product.
if i delete any item from this group,my all group should be deleted
is this possible?

Comment: The view is just a reference back to the data. The sub item will be held underneath the iPhone "cart" in the data. When displaying it you will be able to get **where** it has come from. Whether it's a main item or a sub item etc...

Comment: i have still one question.may i ask?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Go ahead :) will help if I can :)

Comment: there are different products in main and different product in sub.
suppose i click on iphone ,it added to cart
than i click on charger,it added to cart.
i have delete button in tableview.
suppose i click on iphone(Main),than subitems will deleted.

in cart there can be also other data.
so how i can find that this perticular product and sub needs to deleted

Comment: @KrutarthPatel yeah. In the model I suggest the accessories are actually help WITHIN the iPhone cart object. So when you remove the iPhone from the cart you also remove its cart object (and so everything in the cart).

Comment: Thank you.i will check and please stay in touch in this issue

Comment: @KrutarthPatel no worries. The main thing to remember is that the UI is not the same as the data. Make the data model fit your use cases. Make it so that you can delete things and add things like you want. Then the UI can be displayed however you want on top of the data.

Comment: may i know any link to know data model and how its works.so i can create according to my requirements

Comment: @KrutarthPatel there isn't one unfortunately. That's part of being a developer. You have to overcome the obstacles like this that you encounter and part of that is being able to design a data model for your particular program.

Comment: i think by creating sections in tableview we can achieve this functionality.right move?

Comment: i think main product will added to sections in sections and sub product will attached to each section.
plz tell me

Comment: hello brother.i am stuck plz give attention

Comment: I am not here to write your app for you. I have given you advice that you ma or may not choose to follow. As a developer/designer it is for you to apply basic principles and create a data model/UI that suits your needs. If you'd like to hire me for consulting I'd happily discuss contracts and prices with you outside of StackOverflow.